# Parsing data from Wikipedia table

Tags: python

I want to parse data from wikipedia table, and turn in into a pandas dataframe.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI
there is a table called 'version history'
so far I have written following code, but still can't get the data

```
wiki='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI'
table_class='wikitable sortable mw-collapsible mw-no-collapsible jquery-tablesorter 
mw-made-collapsible'
response = requests.get(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

miui_v = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': table_class})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html I downloaded table you are searching for has different class:

> class="wikitable mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible"

I guess it can changes dependend on some browser and their extensions. I recommend to start with element that has id to guarantee match. In your case you can do:

```
miui_v = soup.find("div", {"id": "mw-content-text"})
my_table = miui_v.findChildren("div")[0].findChildren("table")[1]
```